# How can I better design systems and components in ECS?

Tags: design, architecture, c++, game-development, entity-component-system

I'm working on a game from scratch in C++ which is based on an [Entity Component System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity_component_system) and I've ran into a bit of a problem with the way I've been designing my systems and components. I find myself making fairly big systems that handle all the behavior for an entity or in other words I have systems that operate on 1 entity for example I wanted two different camera behaviors a free camera for debugging and third person for gameplay, so I created `DebugCameraSystem` and `ThirdPersonCameraSystem` even for my player I ended up with a `PlayerController`

```
class  ThirdPersonCameraController: public ISystem {
public:
    void Update(float timestep) override {
        // Mouse Input
        if (gInputManager.IsMouseButtonDown(SDL_BUTTON_RIGHT)) {

        }

        // make the camera look at its target
    }
};

class  DebugCameraController : public ISystem {
public:
    void Update(float timestep) override {
        // Mouse Input
        if (gInputManager.IsMouseButtonDown(SDL_BUTTON_RIGHT)) {

        }

        // Keyboard Input
        if (gInputManager.IsKeyDown(SDLK_w)) {
        }

        if (gInputManager.IsKeyDown(SDLK_s)) {
        }
    }
};

class  PlayerController : public ISystem {
public:
    void Update(float timestep) override {
        

        // Keyboard Input
        if (gInputManager.IsKeyDown(SDLK_w)) {
        }

        if (gInputManager.IsKeyDown(SDLK_s)) {
        }

        // Jump
        if (gInputManager.IsKeyDown(SDLK_SPACE)) {
        }

        // Some ability
        if (gInputManager.IsKeyDown(SDLK_e)) {
        }
    }
};
```

I've done a bit of research, and the common solution I've seen seems to be making more general-purpose systems or systems that update components and systems that act on the updated components so instead of having those three systems I'd just have an `InputSystem` and then a `MoveSystem`. This raises a few questions though like how would I implement specific logic like the player shooting a gun or activating abilities? And I think that's what pushed me into my current direction.

Anyways what I'd like to know is my approach valid and I'm just overthinking things or am incorrectly using ECS?

Comment: Can you elaborate on the problem? seems like you are doing ECS here, I assume you have one player "entity" attach all the controllers you want (depending on mode) and each frame update gets called for all attached controllers?

Comment: I guess what I'm trying to ask is do I want a single system that makes up the player or do I want to make multiple systems? So instead of having PlayerController I'd have MoveSystem, JumpSystem, AbilitySystem, etc.

Comment: isnt that what you have here in your example though? playercontroller, cameracontroller etc whats different about calling them systems?

Comment: what problem have you encountered with the current setup that made you look for a solution

Comment: The keypresses in playercontroller wpuld only ever apply the the player right? it doesn't make sense to split them unless you have a whole bunch of characters that should jump when you press jump

Comment: Well, the debug camera and player move in the same way they check W,A,S,D and update a transform component so it doesn't make sense IMO to have that code twice I could probably make a system like MoveSystem that does it for both and potentially anything else. This approach raises some other questions though like what if I wanted to add jumping does it go into the movement system or a player system? Like how far should logic be broken down.

Comment: Yeah, I would assume that the player and the camera move differently, like one can fly etc. if you made a generic one and added some method of overriding the effect of the keypress, youve just added a layer when you have one for that already